# finding checkbox checked in a datalist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use asp.net . I have 3 nested datalist on a page. In inner datalist, there are ckeckboxes. I look likes below.

[image]

my dalist's design is like below:

```
   <asp:DataList ID="grdRubrikKazanimlari" runat="server" 
   OnItemDataBound="grdRubrikKazanimlari_OnItemDataBound" 
   CssClass="grdRubrikKazanimlari" >
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="width:100%;display:block;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblDegTipIliskiID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DegTipIliskiID")%>'></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDegerlendirmeTipiID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DegerlendirmeTipiID")%>'></asp:Label>
      <h1>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDegerlendirmeTipi" runat="server" Text=""><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DegerlendirmeTipi")%></asp:Label>
      </h1>

      <asp:DataList ID="grdRubrikKazanimGrup" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="grdRubrikKazanimGrup_OnItemDataBound" CssClass="grdRubrikKazanimGrup">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width:96%;display:block;margin-left:5px;">
          <asp:Label ID="lblAltGrupIliskiID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AltGrupIliskiID")%>'></asp:Label>
         <h2>
           <asp:Label ID="lblDegerlendirmeTipi" runat="server" Text=""><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AltGrup")%></asp:Label>
         </h2>
          <asp:DataList ID="grdRubrikKazanimlar" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="grdRubrikKazanimlar_OnItemDataBound" CssClass="grdRubrikKazanimlar" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="width:100%;">
           <tr style="line-height:25px;">
            <td style="width:70%;text-align:left;padding-left:12px;font-weight:bold;">Kazanım Açıklaması</td>
            <td style="width:15%;background-color:#91c98f;text-align:center">T.Edinilmiş</td>
            <td style="width:15%;background-color:#bf6f86;text-align:center">T.Edinilmemiş</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblRubrikKazanimID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RubrikKazanimID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
         <table style="width:100%;" id="tblkazanim">
         <tr style="height:50px;vertical-align:middle;">
           <td style="width:70%;text-align:left;padding-left:12px;">
           <li>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDegerlendirmeTipi" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "KazanimAciklama")%>'></asp:Label>
           </li>
           </td>
           <td style="width:15%;background-color:#91c98f;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSeciliMi" runat="server" align="center"  CssClass="chsecili"  OnCheckedChanged="chkSeciliMi_CheckChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
           </td>
           <td style="width:15%;background-color:#bf6f86;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkYarimSeciliMi" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkYarimSeciliMi_CheckChanged" CssClass="chkYarimSeciliMi"/>
           </td>
           </tr>
           </table>
           <div style="width:96%;display:block;">
           <asp:Label ID="lblDegTipIliskiID" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDegerlendirmeTipiID" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
              <asp:Label ID="lblKazanimDegerlendirmeTipiID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DegTipIliskiID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="lblKazanimSirasi" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sirasi")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
          </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:DataList>

        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
       </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I want a user only checks a checkbox on a horizontal line. How can I do this using jquery.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

this should do the trick :)

Combine it with .each if needed :)

If you need only horizontal checks, you should add classes to those checkboxes to make sure you only got the specific checkboxes. (like .row1 .row2 etc)